# Should ALL my css and javascript be in its own folders?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, zend-framework

I have a zend framework project. In the public folder I have js and css folders to deposit the files required by the various actions. However, I have also integrated some other jquery plugins that have their own css and png's.

For instance JqueryUI has its own css and a bunch of png's that it uses (apart from the jquery). By default, these all come bundled inside the jquery folder. Fancybox is the same.

It seems like a might break things and cause myself unnecessary work if I try to separate all of the images,css and javascript for each plugin. On the other hand, I like to keep all my different assets separate and under control.

I am really talking about packages like jqueryui. If I move the css out of the jqueryUI folder (which is inside the js folder) then it will break all of the paths the css has to it's own image directory (which is just below where the css is currently located)....

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: I think it's really a matter of preference. I like to keep separate css, images, and js folders, which might be a little more work up front, but makes it easier for anyone later joining the project to find what they are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For plugins if they come in a package it will be a pain to separate them out.  So I keep them the way they came with, under ThirdParties/`<pluginName>`/.

Answer (score 2):

its always a good practice too keep things organized, when I start a project, my folder structure looks like this

```
- core
  - classes
    - database.class.php
    - ui.class.php
- css
  - styles.css
  - ie6.css
  - ie7.css
  - jquery_ui
    - whatever.css
- javascript
  - jquery.min.js
  - userdrive.js //all the functions and calls I make here
+ images
```

when you have things organized they become easier accessible and if you see a change in styles you can always inspect elements in firebug and see which elements are causing problems.

Comment: Thanks, you are all correct I think. Your input has been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Organization is **always** worth it. Even for a tiny disposable project because you never know what will happen. Organizing now might be a hassle but think about 6 months from now: it will be MUCH harder to do, and imagine trying to explain where to find something to someone else, over the phone, once you haven't touched the code in 3 months... not going to be fun.